# Get-AzAutomationCredential works in Powershell ISE but not in runbook

Tags: azure, powershell, automation

I've been running the Get-AzAutomationCredential cmdlet in powershell ISE and it returns my account, but when I run the same script in my automation account in a runbook, I receive the following:

Code:

```
$autoCredential = get-AzAutomationCredential -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup" -AutomationAccountName "automationaccount" -Name "accountName"

$User = $autoCredential.UserName
```

Output:

`"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."`

The credentials are present in the credentials blade within the automation account.

Answer (score 0):

To make this work you first need to "logon" to Azure to get the Automation Credentials.  Here is an example that connects via the System Assigned Identity.

### Example Script

```
$automationAccount = "<INSERT-ACCOUNT-NAME>"

Connect-AzAccount -Identity 

$allcreds = Get-AzAutomationCredential -AutomationAccountName $automationAccount -ResourceGroupName "AWS-WL"

foreach($cred in $allcreds){
     $credObj = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name $cred.Name
     write-output $credObj.UserName
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this command to get all of the credential names in an azure runbook? I have a use case where I'd like to get all of the credentials and their passwords. I was hoping to use `Get-AzAutomationCredential` to get a list of all of the names and then use `Get-AutomationPSCredential` to get the actual user/pass combinations. I'm not seeing a great way to do this from an azure runbook though.

Comment: See revised answer.